Samsung EVO External Drive not showing up in Windows explorer
I am able to see and explore contents on external hard drive manager (EASEUS Partition Master) But the hard drive is not showing up in windows explorer. What can I do for it to show up in explorer?
Disk Management also seem to not have a letter assigned to the drive. Attached Screenshots.
EaseUS External Drive manager (listing the drive)

Disk Management:

Able to explore fine in EaseUS

Nothing Shows up in windows explorer

Can't see file in diskpart


The partition(s) on the external EVO need to be mounted in Disk Management lr via DiskPart - it's likely the mount points were removed at some point, else a filesystem error can also cause the drive to not auto mount the partitions.

@JW0914 Thanks for the reply. I am not able to see EVO disc or drive in diskpart though.. Updated the screeeenshot of diskpart too.

Wrong command - correct: lis dis. Windows sees four disks per Disk Management, Disks 0 - 3, with the EVO being 3 per EaseUS. To mount the partitions on Disk 3, either right-click the second partition in Disk Management or in DiskPart: sel dis 3→ sel par 2→ assign letter=z→ exit

Not sure how this fixed the problem, but it did:
I created 5 GB partition using EaseUS Pro, and assigned a drive letter using EaseUS Pro. Assigning one using windows didn't work.
